# WARNING The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-profiles

I am trying to run maven goal: validation and keep getting: [WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.

In my org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs:

```
activeProfiles=pom.xml
eclipse.preferences.version=1
resolveWorkspaceProjects=true
version=1
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `pom.xml` probably isn't the id of an active profile.

Answer (score 40):

1. Right click on your project
2. Go to "Run as"
3. Go to "Run configurations... "
4. When the screen opens, please delete the word "pom.xml" from the "Profiles:" line and then click "Run".

The project will now run.

[image: profile]

Comment: Good solution. Got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Your `activeProfiles` is set to `pom.xml`. But your Maven profile should be defined **inside** your `pom.xml` with an `id`. You have to set this id as the active profile or remove this line to use the default profile of your maven project.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project:

1. maven -> disable maven nature
2. configure -> Convert to maven project
3. run As -> Maven clean
4. run As -> Maven install

Answer (score 2):

You just have to:

1. delete .m2 repository.
2. execute mvn clean install.

That solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on the project
2. Select menu **Properties**
3. Click on **Maven** item in the list of left side
4. Look at the right side and removing **pom.xml** from the box
5. Apply & Close

Answer (score 1):

In the Eclipse IDE, you can find the profile ID listed in two places.  The two apparently aren't kept in the same place as I found the profile listed in one place and not the other.

Project-> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Maven Build

If your project is not listed here, then there is no maven profile set.  Before making any changes, make sure the name at the top of the right hand window reads your project name!  The main tab has a box labeled Profiles:

Project->Properties->Maven

Active Maven Profiles appear in the right hand pane.  Simple delete and click apply.  This cleared my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target Java version matches the installed Java version in the `pom.xml`. Even if you have the java version installed. Check if eclipse project facet has correct java version.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```