# Spring Maven clean error - The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to build a Spring-Boot *.war with maven, but I keep getting:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.600 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-28T10:46:11-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

After running the mvn: clean.

I have no idea why, I'm following [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/).

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.bigriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>webconsultas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>WebConsultas</name>
    <description>Sistema de consulta m�dica on the web</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.WebConsultasApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

After the success, maven generates a target folder in the project, it's containing only the Manifest.mf, pom.properties and pom.xml.

I'm a beginner using maven/spring and I haven't find any clues about what it might be. Any help would be appreciated.

The complete log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project webconsultas: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project webconsultas: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: invalid target release: 1.8
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid target release: 1.8
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions$GrumpyHelper.error(RecognizedOptions.java:88)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions$10.process(RecognizedOptions.java:359)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.processOptions(JavacTool.java:242)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:199)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:115)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: What maven command are you using?

Comment: quoting spring guide "At this stage, you are ready to build a WAR file.

mvn clean package
This command creates target/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven-0.1.0.war, a deployable artifact."

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Along the lines of the question asked by Cristiano Fontes, with commands "clean compile" I got this error (was trying to run a mvn command for the first time, before the libraries had even been downloaded). But when running "clean package" everything downloaded and the warning did not come up. I'm still a little mystified.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The warning message

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

means that you somehow passed `-P pom.xml` to Maven which means "there is a profile called `pom.xml`; find it and activate it". Check your environment and your `settings.xml` for this flag and also look at all `<profile>` elements inside the various XML files.

Usually, `mvn help:effective-pom` is also useful to see what the real POM would look like.

Now the error means that you tried to configure Maven to build Java 8 code but you're not using a Java 8 runtime. Solutions:

1. Install Java 8
2. Make sure Maven uses Java 8 if you have it installed. `JAVA_HOME` is your friend
3. Configure the Java compiler in your `pom.xml` to a Java version which you actually have.

Related:

- [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: This may have been marked as the answer, but it was no help to me.  The other answer (with a 4 step response) is the answer that worked for me.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

Answer (score 122):

I was getting this same warning everytime I was doing 'maven clean'. I found the solution :

> **Step - 1** Right click on your project in Eclipse
>
> **Step - 2** Click Properties
>
> **Step - 3** Select Maven in the left hand side list.
>
> **Step - 4** You will notice "pom.xml" in the Active Maven Profiles text box on the right hand side. Clear it and click Apply.

Below is the screen shot:

[image: Properties dialog box]

Comment: this helped me to get pass the profile does not exist problem. Thanks

Comment: For me two steps helped -
1. I had pom.xml missing in the build profile/run configurations. Hence added, built project (clean install) , removed from the profile
2. Removed pom.xml from maven Profile as showed above

Answer (score 13):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756741/452708) has solution of how to get it working.
Removing "pom.xml" from the "Profiles:" line and then click "Run".

Answer (score 5):

1. Right click on your project in STS/ Eclipse.
2. Click Properties.
3. Click Maven on Left Pane.
4. Clear pom.xml in the Active Maven Profiles text box on right hand side.
5. Apply and close.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful. I couldn't figure out why suddenly build was not happening. POM was not active

Answer (score 2):

Goto Properties -> maven 
Remove the pom.xml from the activate profiles and follow the below steps.

Steps :

1. Delete the .m2 repository
2. Restart the Eclipse IDE
3. Refresh and Rebuild it

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into same warning.
If you specified goals and built project using "**Run as -> Maven build...**" option
check and remove **pom.xml** from **Profiles:** just below **Goals:**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the groupId of your project in POM is same as the name of the package where your main class exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes even I got the same error. So I did the following changes

-> Check the error in the Problems tab located near the Console tab

-> See where the error persists, Its possible that some jar file may be corrupted or is outdated so, pom isn't activated in the Project.

-> I found one of my jar was outdated version so I updated it by getting the dependencies from maven repository from this link https://mvnrepository.com

So to conclude, do check where the error persist and which jar file is outdated and make changes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is problem with java configuration.
We need to provide it specifically.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/455761/230548

Change the version of STS to number 4.10 and avoid use versions before 4.10. For example: Using version 3.9.8 it will cause that issue!

Actualiza la versión del STS a la número 4.10 evitando usar versiones anteriores a la 4 Ej. Usar la versión 3.9.8 te genera ese error de que el pom.xml no existe!

Answer (score 0):

Supprised that no one here say to remove the secure connection. In many distributions, secure connections always failed. Check your pom profile, and remove any https, something like:

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the warning you are facing follow these steps

1.Right click on the project

2.select Run as

3.click on Run configurations

4.remove pom.xml in profiles

5.apply and run

```
    -------Mounika.sake
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that the profile may be defined in run/debug configuration

[image]