# Eclipse POM error - MavenArchiver.getManifest

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've just created a new project, below in my Maven POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>tracking</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tracking</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Eclipse (4.5.0) is showing an Error

> org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)   pom.xml /tracking   line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

This message is not very helpful - what could be wrong with the POM?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555557/m2e-error-in-mavenarchiver-getmanifest

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/issues/8

Comment: The hint of S Sourav is correct. Please update your m2e integeration version in eclise...

Comment: Update your m2e plugin.[link] https://otto.takari.io/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.2/N/LATEST/

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54215242/3357884). Hope that helps!

Comment: Stop using eclipse. It is junk.

Answer (score 0):

I changed 2.0.0.RELEASE to 1.5.19.RELEASE

I found the solution in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49313603/5747979

Comment: Please explain how it solved the problem of OP regarding his question.