# Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm encountering these errors every time I run my project as Maven Install. I've tried clearing the maven cache based on other questions but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.561 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-15T23:57:19+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project SpringBootSpringJPACRUD: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Maven clean error - The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192761/spring-maven-clean-error-the-requested-profile-pom-xml-could-not-be-activate)

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error message? It looks like there is a part missing in which the error is described.

Comment: The first one is a WARNING that you have tried to activate a profile which does not exists...But the more important part is that your code has compile errors...