# STS maven project not showing all files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[STS screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbl2X.jpg)
I have created new maven project from start.spring.io

But after importing .jar file in STS tool its not showing src/main/java ,src/main/resources etc files

what to do any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your `POM.xml`  is indicating an error. Have look at your `POM.xml` and fix the error, maybe Maven is unable to find a dependency or your `POM.xml`  is broken (-> bad syntax?). If Maven can properly find all dependencies and accepts your `POM.xml` , STS will then show the correct Maven project structure.

Comment: no error in pon.xml but getting error in build The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.

Comment: have look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232541/warning-the-requested-profile-pom-xml-could-not-be-activated-because-it-does-n