# Spring Boot Multi module project - Build issues due to compilation issues for imports from different module

Tags: java, maven, build, multi-module

We have a multi-module Spring boot project starting from scratch, the hierarchy is like this

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] hh                                                                 [pom]
[INFO] common-service                                                     [jar]
[INFO] account-service                                                    [jar]
[INFO] product-service                                                    [jar]
[INFO] auth-service                                                       [jar]
[INFO] application-service                                                [war]
```

**This is the pom.xml of the `account-service`.**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.hh.sukku</groupId>
        <artifactId>hh</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>account-service</artifactId>
    <name>account-service</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- Project module dependencies start -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hh.sukku</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Project module dependencies end -->
    
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**This is the parent module pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.hh.sukku</groupId>
    <artifactId>hh</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>hh</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>application-service</module>
        <module>common-service</module>
        <module>account-service</module>
        <module>product-service</module>
        <module>auth-service</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The problem comes with the Controller in the `account-service`, the response bean and the error code of the API come from the `common-service`. Initially while importing it showed compilation issues for both but after doing a `maven-update` there were no errors.

**This is the controller**

```
package com.hh.sukku.account.controller;

import static com.hh.sukku.common.util.ErrorCodes.SUCCESS;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.hh.sukku.account.dto.UserDTO;
import com.hh.sukku.account.service.UserService;
import com.hh.sukku.common.beans.Response;

/**
 * 
 * @author arun.sudhakaran
 *
 * 02-Apr-2023 11:14:15 pm
 */

@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/user")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(path = "", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> create(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO request) {
        
        userService.create(request);
        
        Response response = new Response(SUCCESS, "Success");
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The problem starts when we try to do a `maven clean install` on the parent module, it fails with this error

**Console output of Maven clean install**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] hh                                                                 [pom]
[INFO] common-service                                                     [jar]
[INFO] account-service                                                    [jar]
[INFO] product-service                                                    [jar]
[INFO] auth-service                                                       [jar]
[INFO] application-service                                                [war]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.hh.sukku:hh >---------------------------
[INFO] Building hh 1.0.0                                                  [1/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ hh ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\hh\haraji\workspace\hh\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ hh ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.hh.sukku:common-service >---------------------
[INFO] Building common-service 1.0.0                                      [2/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ common-service ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\hh\haraji\workspace\hh\common-service\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ common-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ common-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to D:\hh\haraji\workspace\hh\common-service\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ common-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ common-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ common-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar (default-jar) @ common-service ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\hh\haraji\workspace\hh\common-service\target\common-service-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ common-service ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.hh.sukku:account-service >--------------------
[INFO] Building account-service 1.0.0                                     [3/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\hh\haraji\workspace\hh\account-service\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 17 source files to D:\hh\haraji\workspace\hh\account-service\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[21,37] package com.hh.sukku.common.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[22,34] package com.hh.sukku.common.params does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[23,32] package com.hh.sukku.common.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[47,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ParamsFileOperations
  location: class com.hh.sukku.account.service.FileUploadService
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[3,39] package com.hh.sukku.common.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[3,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[25,33] package com.hh.sukku.common.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[26,33] package com.hh.sukku.common.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[27,32] package com.hh.sukku.common.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/UserService.java:[19,33] package com.hh.sukku.common.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/UserService.java:[20,37] package com.hh.sukku.common.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[50,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[60,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PagedResponse
  location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/UserService.java:[59,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PagedResponse
  location: class com.hh.sukku.account.service.UserService
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[61,70] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Constants
  location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[62,70] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Constants
  location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[64,71] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Constants
  location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[INFO] 17 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] hh 1.0.0 ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.689 s]
[INFO] common-service ..................................... SUCCESS [  8.217 s]
[INFO] account-service .................................... FAILURE [  3.859 s]
[INFO] product-service .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] auth-service ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] application-service 1.0.0 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.033 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-11T22:39:59+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project account-service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[21,37] package com.hh.sukku.common.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[22,34] package com.hh.sukku.common.params does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[23,32] package com.hh.sukku.common.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/FileUploadService.java:[47,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ParamsFileOperations
[ERROR]   location: class com.hh.sukku.account.service.FileUploadService
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[3,39] package com.hh.sukku.common.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[3,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[25,33] package com.hh.sukku.common.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[26,33] package com.hh.sukku.common.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[27,32] package com.hh.sukku.common.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/UserService.java:[19,33] package com.hh.sukku.common.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/UserService.java:[20,37] package com.hh.sukku.common.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[50,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Response
[ERROR]   location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[60,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class PagedResponse
[ERROR]   location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/service/UserService.java:[59,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class PagedResponse
[ERROR]   location: class com.hh.sukku.account.service.UserService
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[61,70] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Constants
[ERROR]   location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[62,70] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Constants
[ERROR]   location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] /D:/hh/haraji/workspace/hh/account-service/src/main/java/com/hh/sukku/account/controller/UserController.java:[64,71] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Constants
[ERROR]   location: class com.hh.sukku.account.controller.UserController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :account-service
```

We even tried `maven clean install -X` and `maven install` individually on the `account-service`. All attempts failed with the same error.

The fun fact is that the application can be started successfully but when we try to hit the API we are getting `404`. What could be missing? There are no visible compilation errors.

The other interesting fact is that when we tried to import the controller from the `account-service` into the `application-service` and tried to build `application-service` it was a success. But when we tried to import a bean from the `common-service` the same got failed, so we can narrow down that the issue is with the `common-service`.

But at some point when we started the `application-service` we were able to process the request and insert data into the table, so we tried to build the parent pom, but again it failed. Later the application started giving 404 again for the same request.

**Major changes with initial edit**

1. One thing we found was that the `groupId` of the modules was not the same as the parent, so we created a new one with all of them having the same `groupId`. The issue remained the same.
2. We hardcoded the parent versions to every module and their dependencies, but the issue remained the same.
3. We tried to import the `Response` bean from the `Fix project setup...` option and locate the bean in the popup. The issue remained the same.
4. We newly created the same project and added the new modules by checking the options `Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)` and `Add project(s) to the working set`, but the issue remained the same.
5. There was a warning with the parent pom.xml, so we removed the `pom` from the profile section in the run configuration ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756741/7218656)), but the issue remained the same.
6. We even tried `compile package`, which was successful, and two war files were generated `application-service-1.0.0.war` and `hh-1.0.0.war`. But the deployment was not fine, there were no logs of a spring boot application startup and requests were giving `404`.

**Major changes with @Toerktumlare's suggestions**

1. Removed the child modules from the `.m2`, and performed `mvn clean package` the result was the same failure.
2. Added the compiler plugin and performed step-1, failed again.
3. Tried running this command `--projects account-service --also-make clean package` for individual modules. First was `common-service` and it was successful, but with `account-service` it failed saying

   `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project account-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.hh.sukku:account-service:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.hh.sukku:common-service:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

Project URL : https://github.com/Arun-Sudhakaran/hh

Comment: Please, can you post the complete maven output of compilation from the parent?. I think there could be some problems with the `${project.version}` resolution.

Comment: @JMSilla I've updated the full console output of the `maven clean install` on the parent module.

Comment: It seems like you are using a Java version in the IDE and another version with Maven. You must assure that you are using Java 11 (the Java version defined on the project) on both parts. Check `JAVA_HOME` value before doing `mvn clean install`, it must reference a JDK 11 directory.

Comment: @JMSilla the versions in both IDE and the maven is the same.  The `JAVA_HOME` is pointing towards the JDK11 location itself. My other projects are having no such issue with the JDK version. Also, if it is a version issue why that error is occurring only when I use `common-service` classes and not the `account-service` classes? You can see at the bottom of my question I've mentioned the same.

Comment: You can try some things that can help you to detect the problem:
- You can try to change the project version and recompile from parent, checking if all the files are copied in the .m2 directory.
- You can try to make independent projects (with no parent) and compile them in the right order.

Comment: i would first go into the .m2 folder and find common-service, application-service, account service and delete thos so that maven doesn't use them. I would then instead build with `mvn clean package` this will compile and package your application and not install (copy) the jars to your .m2 folder so that we can eliminate some sort of caching issue.

Comment: second is to declare a baseline `pluginManagement` section in the base `pom.xml` declaring the compiler plugin with a base compiler version so that all modules use the same compiler and version to build all modules https://www.baeldung.com/maven-plugin-management#core-plugins

Comment: third is to start building projects part by part, start with building common separate, then account, then application using the command stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57186296/1840146 so for example `mvn --projects account-service --also-make clean package`

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I've tried your methods but it is still failing. I've updated my efforts in the question.

Comment: then you need to get a minimal reproducible example up on github or something for us to pull home and try for ourselfes

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I've added the Git link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a test application was provided i managed to build the project after i applied what i recommended as a second course of action in the comments above which had not been implemented.

So by adding the following in the pom.xml i managed to compile the project

hh/pom.xml

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement> <!-- this line here -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement> <!-- and this line here -->
</build>
```

you can read more about `pluginManagement`in the following links:

[plugin management baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-plugin-management)

[what is plugin management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/what-is-pluginmanagement-in-mavens-pom-xml)

[difference between plugins and pluginmanagement tag in maven pom xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736876/difference-between-plugins-and-pluginmanagement-tag-in-maven-pom-xml)

Comment: It really worked, thanks. So it was all because of that tag, right? I downloaded the project from **start.spring.io** and it was like that. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: For future reference, so that other users don't have to go through all the above question, the issue occurred because in my parent `pom.xml` I didn't encapsulate my `<plugins>` inside `<pluginManagement>`.

Comment: `start.spring.io` does not supply a multi-module project. How to setup such a project is documented in the maven docs

Comment: I mean the parent module was taken from **start.spring.io**

Comment: And then you need to modify it if you want to create a multi module project