# Unable to build multi module Spring boot Project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am able to run services, do any spring operations using project but not able to compile at spring 3.0 project.

Added dependencies at Parent pom.xml, added, Spring plugin management at dependency.
Compiled with deleting m2 repository files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- List item
  This has been already answered at:
  [Spring Boot Multi module project - Build issues due to compilation issues for imports from different module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75916464/spring-boot-multi-module-project-build-issues-due-to-compilation-issues-for-im)

Please view the link it solved my question.
One change in the solution given the </*> needs to added at parent pom.xml